# How to create filter across the prototype?

Tags: javascript

In the "Team" class there is a "kick" method, its essence is to randomly select a target if it is alive, respectively, to cause damage. How to make each character (archer, mage, swordsman) first look for the purpose of its class, (that is, archer "kick" archer, swordsman "kick" swordsman, etc.) and if its "isAlive" = "false" hero tried to hit a random target? I get the "TypeError: sameTypeUnit .__ proto__ is not a function" error on condition that the prototype coincides.

```js
//constructor for creating a unit
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage,type) {
    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.currentHealth = maxHealth;
    this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this.type = type;
}
/*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
 than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
Unit.prototype.isAlive = function () {
    return this.currentHealth > 0;
};
/* a method that
 shows the level of health*/
Unit.prototype.getFormattedHealth = function () {
    return this.currentHealth + "/" + this.maxHealth + " HP";
};
/*a method that returns the base damage of the hero and damage to the
 weapon (if it is set)*/
Unit.prototype.getDamage = function () {
    return this.basicDamage;
};
/* The method of hitting
 the hero for the chosen purpose*/
Unit.prototype.kick = function (target) {
    if (this.isAlive()) {
        target.currentHealth = Math.max(0,
            target.currentHealth - this.getDamage());
        console.log(this.type + " hit " + this.type);
    }
    return this;
};
/*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
 with them*/
Unit.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Type - " + this.type + ", is alive - " +
        this.isAlive() + ", " + this.getFormattedHealth() +
        ', hero current damage - ' + this.getDamage() + ' points';
};
/*the constructors of the main types of units  which we will use*/
function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "archer";
}
function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "swordsman";
}
function Mage(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "mage";
}
Archer.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
Swordsman.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
Mage.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
/*We create units of which we will then write to the teams.
 Three units per team*/
var archer = new Archer(60, 5);
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10);
var mage = new Mage(40, 15);

var troll = new Archer(70, 5);
var orc = new Swordsman(150, 10);
var druid = new Mage(50, 15);

/*class for creating teams*/
function Team(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.members = [];
    this.activeMember = 0;
}
/*method for adding a new unit with an arbitrary number of units*/
Team.prototype.addMember = function (...members) {
    this.members.push(...members);
}
/*method of life of the team, if all participants have
"currentHealth" <0 then this method = "false"*/
Team.prototype.isAlive = function () {
    return this.members.some(n => n.isAlive());
};
/*Damage method similar to that in "Unit" in it the choice
is made - who is attacking whom (the team members take turns
attacking the random participant of the other team)*/
Team.prototype.kick = function(targetTeam) {

    var sameTypeUnit = null;
    for(var i=0;i<this.members.length;i++) {
        sameTypeUnit = this.members[i];
    }
    if (sameTypeUnit.__proto__(sameTypeUnit) && sameTypeUnit.isAlive()) {
        while (sameTypeUnit.isAlive()) {
            sameTypeUnit.kick(sameTypeUnit);
        }
    }else if (!sameTypeUnit.isAlive()) {
        var m = targetTeam.members.filter(n => n.isAlive())
        target = m[Math.random() * m.length | 0];
        if (target && this.isAlive()) {
            var active = null;

            do  {
                active = this.members[this.activeMember];
                this.activeMember = (this.activeMember + 1)
                    % this.members.length;
            } while (!active.isAlive());

            active.kick(target);
        }
    }
};
/*method to output information about the team*/
Team.prototype.toString = function () {
    var res = "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n'
        + "life of a team : " + this.isAlive() + '\n'
        +"members :\n";
    for (var i=0; i<this.members.length; i++)
        res += this.members[i]+"\n";
    return  res;
};
/*create team 1 and add units to it*/
var team1 =  new Team('Alliance');
team1.addMember(archer,swordsman,mage);
/*create team 2 and add units to it*/
var team2 = new Team('Orcs');
team2.addMember(troll,orc,druid);

/*class that organizes a battle between two teams until
 "currentHealth" of all units in the team will not be zero*/
function Game(team1, team2) {
    this.team1 = team1;
    this.team2 = team2;
}
/*the method in which the battle occurs until the
"isAlive" property of all participants of one of the commands
 is equal to "false"*/
Game.prototype.battle = function() {
    if (!this.team1.isAlive() || !this.team2.isAlive()) {
        if (this.team1.isAlive()) {
            alert("Team 1 is win");
        }
        if (this.team2.isAlive()) {
            alert("Team 2 is win");
        }
        console.log(`THE BATTLE IS END :
        ${this.team1.toString()}
        ${this.team2.toString()}
      ${this.team1.name} - ${this.team1.members.length} - 
${this.team1.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}
      ${this.team2.name} - ${this.team2.members.length} -
${this.team2.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}  
    `);
        return;
    }
    team1.kick(team2);
    team2.kick(team1);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.battle.bind(this));
};
var game = new Game(team1, team2);
game.battle();
```

Comment: Never ever use `__proto__` and you definetly cannot call it. Could you describe what `sameTypeUnit.__proto__(sameTypeUnit) ` should do?

Comment: Did not understand why you have this part `for(var i=0;i<this.members.length;i++) {
        sameTypeUnit = this.members[i];
    }`. Did you close that curly brace too early and meant to run through all team members?

Comment: search for the same hero and attack him ("archer" "kick" "archer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you just want to `filter` the enemies members based on the current attacker:

```
Team.prototype.kick = function(targetTeam) {
  for(const member of this.members) {
    // Filter the enemies based on their type
    const enemies = targetTeam.members.filter(m => m.type === member.type);
    // If there are no enemies with the same type, take another one:
    if(!enemies.length) enemies.push(...targetTeam.members);
    // TODO: Shuffle
    // Attack enemies as long as there are some...
     while(enemies.length && member.isAlive()) {
       member.kick( enemies[0] );
       if(!enemies[0].isAlive()) enemies.shift();
     }
  }
}
```

---

Another approach would be to sort the enemies, so that the ones of the same type come first, and then shuffle it a bit:

```
  /* Clones and Shuffles the array, but moves enemies with the same type to the front */
 function typeFirstShuffle(array, type) {
   return [...array].sort((a, b) => 
     (a.type === type) - (b.type === type) || // same type first
     Math.random() * 2 - 1 // otherwise shuffle
   );
}
```

Which can be used as

```
Team.prototype.kick = function(targetTeam) {
  for(const member of this.members) {
    const enemies = typeFirstShuffle(targetTeam.members, member.type);
   // ... Same as above
  }
}
```

Comment: Each character (archer, magician, swordsman) must first look for the target of his class, and if it is not, then try to strike a random target.

Comment: @igor i understood that (hopefully) and thats what this answer tries to do :)

Comment: And why when I write "console.log (this.name)" before member.kick (enemies [0]);
I see that only one team is attacking "Alliance" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try making use of ES6's class and inhgeritance system. It'll make it a little clean and easier. But the main problem is in the logic of your team kick. There's way too many redundant and uneeded conditionals. I rewrote the entire thing using class inheritence but the over all logic of the kick functiuon is what needs to change

```js
class Unit {
  constructor(maxHealth, basicDamage, classType)
  {
    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.currentHealth = maxHealth;
    this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this.type = classType;


  }
  isAlive()
  {
    return this.currentHealth > 0;
  }

  getFormattedHealth()
  {
    return this.currentHealth + "/" + this.maxHealth + " HP";
  }

  getDamage()
  {
    return this.basicDamage;
  }

  kick(target)
  {
    if (this.isAlive()) {
      target.currentHealth = Math.max(0,
          target.currentHealth - this.getDamage());
      console.log(this.type + " hit " + target.type);
    }
    return this;
  }

  toString()
  {
    return "Type - " + this.type + ", is alive - " +
      this.isAlive() + ", " + this.getFormattedHealth() +
      ', hero current damage - ' + this.getDamage() + ' points';
  }
}


class Archer extends Unit
{
  constructor(maxHealth, basicDamage)
  {
    super(maxHealth, basicDamage, "archer");
  }
}
class Swordsman extends Unit
{
  constructor(maxHealth, basicDamage)
  {
    super(maxHealth, basicDamage, "swordsman");
  }
}
class Mage extends Unit
{
  constructor(maxHealth, basicDamage)
  {
    super(maxHealth, basicDamage, "mage");
  }
}

/*We create units of which we will then write to the teams.
 Three units per team*/
var archer = new Archer(60, 5);
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10);
var mage = new Mage(40, 15);

var troll = new Archer(70, 5);
var orc = new Swordsman(150, 10);
var druid = new Mage(50, 15);


class Team
{
  constructor(name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.members = [];
    this.activeMember = 0;
  }

  addMember(...memebrsToAdd)
  {
    memebrsToAdd.forEach(mem => this.members.push(mem));
  }

  isAlive()
  {
    return this.members.some(n => n.isAlive());
  }

  selectRandomTarget(targetTeam)
  {
    let numberOfMembers = targetTeam.members.length;
    let target = null;
    while(target == null || !target.isAlive())
    {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfMembers);
      target = targetTeam.members[randomIndex];
    }
    return target;
  }

  kick(targetTeam) {
    console.log(`\nTeam ${this.name} is attacking`);

    for(var i=0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
      let singleMember = this.members[i];

      if(!this.isAlive()) break;
      if(!singleMember.isAlive()) continue;
      let target = this.selectRandomTarget(targetTeam);
      singleMember.kick(target);
    }

    
  }

  toString() {
    var res = "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n'
        + "life of a team : " + this.isAlive() + '\n'
        +"members :\n";
    for (var i=0; i<this.members.length; i++)
        res += this.members[i]+"\n";
    return  res;
  }
}

/*create team 1 and add units to it*/
var team1 =  new Team('Alliance');
team1.addMember(archer,swordsman,mage);
/*create team 2 and add units to it*/
var team2 = new Team('Orcs');
team2.addMember(troll,orc,druid);

class Game
{
  constructor(team1, team2)
  {
    this.team1 = team1;
    this.team2 = team2;
  }

  battle()
  {
    let currentTeam = team1
    while(this.team1.isAlive() && this.team2.isAlive())
    {
      let defendingTeam = currentTeam === team1 ? team2 : team1;
      currentTeam.kick(defendingTeam);
      currentTeam = currentTeam === team1 ? team2 : team1;
    }
    this.displayWinningMessage();
  }

  displayWinningMessage()
  {
    console.log(`THE BATTLE IS END :
      ${this.team1.toString()}
      ${this.team2.toString()}
      ${this.team1.name} - ${this.team1.members.length} - 
      ${this.team1.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}
      ${this.team2.name} - ${this.team2.members.length} -
      ${this.team2.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}`
    );
  }
}
var game = new Game(team1, team2);
game.battle();
```